# How to make Excel ignore blank cells using VBA code within show all combinations code?

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code that is giving me all possible combinations of data from 7 different columns within Excel. However, at the moment I have to define the specific ranges that are filled so as not to have partially blank product configurations output. I would like each of the 7 columns to have 50 cell ranges selected, that way as more product options are added the macro can just be re-run without having to go in and update the desired ranges within the VBA code. As the code is now, any cell within the 2-52 cell range that is blank, outputs a configured product with a blank option. Can I get the macro to ignore blank cells and only output configurations based on filled cells?

```
Sub ListAllCombinations()
'Updateby Extendoffice
Dim xDRg1, xDRg2, xDRg3, xDRg4, xDRg5, xDRg6, xDRg7 As Range
Dim xRg  As Range
Dim xStr As String
Dim xFN1, xFN2, xFN3, xFN4, xFN5, xFN6, xFN7 As Integer
Dim xSV1, xSV2, xSV3, xSV4, xSV5, xSV6, xSV7 As String
Set xDRg1 = Range("A2:A3")  'First column data
Set xDRg2 = Range("B2:B3")  'Second column data
Set xDRg3 = Range("C2:C3")  'Third column data
Set xDRg4 = Range("D2:D2")  'Fourth column data
Set xDRg5 = Range("E2:E2")  'Fifth column data
Set xDRg6 = Range("F2:F3")  'Sixth column data
Set xDRg7 = Range("G2:G2")  'Seventh column data
xStr = "-"   'Separator
Set xRg = Range("L2")  'Output cell
For xFN1 = 1 To xDRg1.Count
    xSV1 = xDRg1.Item(xFN1).Text
    For xFN2 = 1 To xDRg2.Count
        xSV2 = xDRg2.Item(xFN2).Text
      For xFN3 = 1 To xDRg3.Count
          xSV3 = xDRg3.Item(xFN3).Text
        For xFN4 = 1 To xDRg4.Count
            xSV4 = xDRg4.Item(xFN4).Text
          For xFN5 = 1 To xDRg5.Count
              xSV5 = xDRg5.Item(xFN5).Text
            For xFN6 = 1 To xDRg6.Count
                xSV6 = xDRg6.Item(xFN6).Text
              For xFN7 = 1 To xDRg7.Count
                  xSV7 = xDRg7.Item(xFN7).Text
                  xRg.Value = xSV1 & xStr & xSV2 & xStr & xSV3 & xStr & xSV4 & xStr & xSV5 & xStr & xSV6 & xStr & xSV7 & xStr
                  Set xRg = xRg.Offset(1, 0)
                   Next
                Next
             Next
          Next
       Next
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: 1. This will be slow instead fill variant arrays of just the cells with data(there are many examples on how to find the last cell with a value in a column) and use a variant array to hold the output. 2. 50^7 is more than a single column can hold so that would need to be dealt with.

Comment: It might help if you show your situation and specifically what you're trying to do. Perhaps upload a screenshot? There's a lot in your code that could be improved upon, most notably using arrays. You also are probably not defining variables appropriately.  You have to specify each variable, if not, it's `Variant` which at the moment would be `xFN1, xFN2, xFN3, xFN4, xFN5, xFN6`, and `xSV1, xSV2, xSV3, xSV4, xSV5, xSV6,` etc.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

### List Combinations

- Be careful though, you may run out of rows (`1048576`).

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ListAllCombinations()
    Const ProcName As String = "ListAllCombinations"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const sfRow As Long = 2
    Const sColsList As String = "A,B,C,D,E,F,G"
    
    Const dName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const dFirst As String = "L2"
    Const dSeparator As String = "="
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    Dim wrCount As Long: wrCount = sws.Rows.Count - sfRow + 1
    
    Dim sCols() As String: sCols = Split(sColsList, ",")
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = UBound(sCols) + 1
    Dim Ranges() As Range: ReDim Ranges(1 To cCount)
    Dim CellsCounts() As Long: ReDim CellsCounts(1 To cCount)
    Dim drCount As Long: drCount = 1
    
    Dim rg As Range
    Dim c As Long
    
    For c = 1 To cCount
        On Error Resume Next
        Set Ranges(c) = sws.Cells(sfRow, sCols(c - 1)).Resize(wrCount) _
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        On Error GoTo ClearError
        If Ranges(c) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        CellsCounts(c) = Ranges(c).Cells.Count
        drCount = drCount * CellsCounts(c)
    Next c
    
    Dim dData() As String: ReDim dData(1 To drCount, 1 To cCount)
    
    Dim r As Long
    Dim dr As Long
    Dim cc As Long
    Dim StringRepeats As Long
    Dim SequenceRepeats As Long
    Dim CurrentString As String
    For c = 1 To cCount
        dr = 1
        StringRepeats = drCount
        For cc = 1 To c
            StringRepeats = StringRepeats / CellsCounts(cc)
        Next cc
        SequenceRepeats = 1
        If c > 1 Then
            For cc = 1 To c - 1
                SequenceRepeats = SequenceRepeats * CellsCounts(cc)
            Next cc
        End If
        For cc = 1 To SequenceRepeats
            For r = 1 To CellsCounts(c)
                CurrentString = CStr(Ranges(c).Cells(r).Value)
                For dr = dr To dr + StringRepeats - 1
                    dData(dr, c) = CurrentString
                Next dr
            Next r
        Next cc
    Next c
    
    ' Write results to first column.
    Dim dsLength As Long: dsLength = Len(dSeparator)
    For dr = 1 To drCount
        CurrentString = vbNullString
        For c = 1 To cCount
            CurrentString = CurrentString & dData(dr, c) & dSeparator
        Next c
        dData(dr, 1) = Left(CurrentString, Len(CurrentString) - dsLength)
    Next dr
    
    ' Write.
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Range(dFirst)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dfCell.Resize(drCount)
    drg.Value = dData
    ' Clear.
    Dim dcrg As Range: Set dcrg = dfCell _
        .Resize(dws.Rows.Count - dfCell.Row - drCount + 1).Offset(drCount)
    dcrg.Clear
    ' Autofit.
    dfCell.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    
ProcExit:
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "(" & ProcName & ") " & "Run-time error '" _
       & Err.Number & "': " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub
```